# How To Avoiding Loops When Fetching Users with Owned Equipment and Including User Field in Equipment Fetch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, entity

I started coding a backend for a web app with Spring Boot. I have two classes; the first is 'User,' and the second is 'Equipment.' Now, for the 'User,' it has a list of equipments called 'ownedEquipments':

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "currentUser" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Equipment> ownedEquipments = new ArrayList<>();
```

And for the 'Equipment,' it has an attribute called 'currentUser,' representing the user that owns the equipment:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User currentUser;
```

The problem now is that when I try to fetch a user that has some equipments, it creates in the response object a loop of users inside equipment inside user. Does anyone have any idea?

And here is the link to the project on GitHub if someone needs to see the whole code: https://github.com/AdibChiguer/EquipPro-PFE

I want to fetch the user with their owned equipment without using a loop. Similarly, when I fetch the equipment, I also want to include the user field without using a loop. I tried using the ignore annotation, but in some cases, I still want to retrieve the fields that I ignored.

Comment: You have circular references, that can generate problem especially with lombok and json serializations, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300507/175554 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825789/175554 . I would suggest to use uni direction design of entities, it will be easier to understand and run for you and for hibernate.